# R find output from a csv file with conditions

Tags: r

I have a file named input.csv as below:

```
ID  AVal    BVal    CVAL
ABC 1137169 386321  as
BCD 567314  95504   abc
BCD 567314  890 bcd
BCD 567315  15000   abc
BCD 567314  15000   abc
XYZ 366628  1093668 abc
XYZ 12  1093668 abc
XYZ 139 123 abc
```

Condition:

if ID =same then
    check corresponding A value and B value
    if A value is == A value of that row OR B value == B value of that row

```
Take the matching row and put it in the output file.
```

eg. 1st ID value of ID is "ABC", since ABC is not present anywhere in the ID column, skip it.
2nd value is "BCD", if we iterate through the list we find the 3rd row's id "BCD"
    Check Aval of 2nd row with Aval of 3rd OR Bval of 2nd row with Bval of 3rd, since they match we pick the row.
        BCD == BCD
            if ((567314 == 567314) OR (95504 == 890 )
                pick "BCD   567314  890 bcd" and paste it in output file.

The output will be like below:

Output:

```
ID  AVal    BVal    CVAL
BCD 567314  890 bcd
BCD 567314  15000   abc
XYZ 12  1093668 abc
```

Comment: Maybe edit the algorithm also (I edited the in and output for readability - 4 spaces to the left result in formatted code block)? The algo looks like it had structure ...

Comment: welcome to SO. Try to come up with reproducible example. Use `dput(yourdata)` respectively `dput(head(yourdata))` and paste the output here, so we can help solve the problem more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr::group_by` and `base::duplicated`, for each `ID` check for duplicates in `AVal` `OR` `BVal`

```
#replace below path with complete path of input.csv

DF = read.csv("full/path/to/input.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
subDF = 
DF %>% 
group_by(ID)  %>% 
filter(duplicated(AVal)|duplicated(BVal)) %>% 
as.data.frame()

subDF
#      ID   AVal    BVal CVAL
#1 BCD 567314     890  bcd
#2 BCD 567314   15000  abc
#3 XYZ     12 1093668  abc

#write to output file
write.csv(subDF,"output.csv")
```

Comment: Dear Ossan, Thank you for your prompt reply. However, I need to first match ID, then only I need to compare AVAL andBVAL